# Why Coulomb crystal doesn't appear?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, crystals, coulombs-law, ion-traps

I am cooling randomly placed ions in a [Paul trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_ion_trap) to 0 K in the [LAMMPS Molecular Dynamics Simulator](https://www.lammps.org) package. The script is correct I think. The problem is that for trap configurations from the first example in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.10514.pdf) article, I am getting beautiful symmetric pictures of a [Coulomb crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_crystal) for 10 and 100 particles:

[image]
[image]

but for higher voltages a crystal doesn't appear and the atoms are placed chaotically. What possibly can I misunderstand?

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you allowing for micromotion and the effective heating effect which is to do with the non-linear nature of the $1/r^2$ Coulomb repulsion forces? (i.e. not just Hooke's law spring)

Comment: How can I reduce this heating? I tried to increase cooling but it didn't help. Crystal just can't appear for voltages bigger ~860 volt

Comment: I don't think it can be reduced except by making the equations in the software be non-physical. Another issue is that if your parameters happen to be unfortunately chosen then you might get a genuine instability of the system. You can explore that by creeping up on any given parameter choice and trying nearby parameter choices. I have done these kinds of simulation but that is about as far as I took it.

Comment: thank you for your answer very much, at least I am more confident now that it's not my guilt

Comment: @Andrew Steane
 yea, I checked velocities and they increases by 1000 times for big voltages

Comment: https://www.lammps.org/forum.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: https://www.lammps.org/books.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because debugging why your code didn't work really isn't something for this SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said in the comments, for high voltages ions begin to gain energy from source and temperature increases and crystal can't be formed